# Can not see CKEditor panel on active admin interfaces with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ckeditor, activeadmin

Anyone tried integrating CKEditor on a Rails 3.1 application with active_admin?? I am successful on the part of normal forms... but not with the forms on active_admin interfaces. Say I have a product entry form which only admin users can update or insert... Now as I needed more customized look I made a partial of product form and used formastic code on that as active_admin relies upon that. CKEditor is supposed to work with formastic fields as well... but I can only see a normal textarea field... can anyone help me out here what I am missing out??

I am using **ckeditor** gem for this.
On the formastic form I have a field named description and I added this line for the ckeditor on active_admin product entry form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @product] do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :price %>
    <%= f.input :description, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :height => 400 } %>
    <%= f.input :image, :as => :file %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons :commit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm facing the same issue.  Works fine locally, but crashes on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

ckeditor activates on inputs with class 'ckeditor' by default. So you can write:

`f.input :description, :input_html => { :class => "ckeditor" }`

It's works for me

Answer (score 1):

for some strange reason for me it worked to add

```
#= require ckeditor/init
```

in active_admin.js.coffee

initially I added it to application.js like this

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

but strangely it wasn't enough